# What is the method for clearing a browser cache for Mac that is different than for a PC?

Tags: macos, browser-cache

I have tried numerous tried and true methods for clearing the browser cache plus flushing dns and nothing seems to work. Amazingly, when I pull up the web page on my PC laptop, it works!  But not on my iMac, Macbook Pro, iPad, iPhone, cellular or wi-fi connection, Chrome (synced or not, including incognito), Firefox and Safari.

I've tried:
- CMD + R with and without shift key.
- F5
- Settings > clear cache in all 3 browsers
- sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder; sleep 2; (numerous flavors)
- flush dns /all

In code inspector, I see the new CSS and again, it works on my PC using Chrome.  But, the Apple devices will simply NOT let go of the old style.

Here's the page:
https://fcob.websitedevelopment.net/

The menu is showing a serif font but only on macs.

Here's the CSS code:

```
.main-navigation a, .menu-toggle {
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Would love to know how to clear this stubborn cache issue that appears to be at the mac/apple level and NOT the network, browser or ISP level.

Comment: The simplest thing to thwart a browser cache is to append a bogus query parameter on the end of the URL.  (e.g. `https://fcob.websitedevelopment.net?x=1`).  With that in mind, this sounds more like a font availability problem rather than a caching problem.  I'm not sure if Centry-Gothic exists on Mac?  Have you tried specifying alternate fonts?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the answer!  The CSS should be:

```
.main-navigation a, .menu-toggle {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Must have "sans-serif" included in font-family.  Seems PCs have this font but not Macs?  That's my guess.

Comment: Exactly what I said in the comments above. Century Gothic is a font installed by Microsoft office (might be in Windows).